# skip copying to tmp table on disk mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question for large mysql queries. Is it possible to skip the **copying to tmp table on disk** step that mysql takes for large queries or is it possible to make it go faster? because this step is taking way too long to get the results of my queries back. I read on the MySQL page that mysql performs this to save memory, but I don't care about saving memory I just want to get the results of my queries back FAST, I have enough memory on my machine. Also, my tables are properly indexed so that's not the reason why my queries are slow.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: I'm no MySql expert, but your probably better off optimizing the query and/or schema.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "not a real question."  Question does not include the SQL query to optimize, nor the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to show what indexes, nor the `EXPLAIN` report showing the current optimization plan.

Comment: I would have to agree with @Bill Karwin in needing to see the queries, create table statements, and/or EXPLAIN plans. My answer would solve the problem you see but allow bad queries to bloat RAM. Knowing the nature of your queries would probably eliminate the need to reconfigure either RAM or mysql.

Comment: @ close voters, please have a look at the awesome answer to this question and consider how much visitors this question might have brought to SO. Vote **Leave open**!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are two things you can do to lessen the impact by this

**OPTION #1 : Increase the variables [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and/or [max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size)**

These options will govern how large an in-memory temp table can be before it is deemed too large and then pages to disk as a temporary MyISAM table. The larger these values are, the less likely you will get 'copying to tmp table on disk'. Please, make sure your server has enough RAM and [**max_connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) is moderately configured should a single DB connection need a lot of RAM for its own temp tables.

**OPTION #2 : Use a RAM disk for tmp tables**

You should be able to configure a RAM disk in Linux and then set the [**tmpdir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) in mysql to be the folder that has the RAM disk mounted.

For starters, configure a RAM disk in the OS

Create a folder in the Linux called /var/tmpfs

```
mkdir /var/tmpfs
```

Next, add this line to /etc/fstab (for example, if you want a 16GB RAM disk)

```
none                    /var/tmpfs              tmpfs   defaults,size=16g        1 2
```

and reboot the server.

Note : It is possible to make a RAM disk without rebooting. Just remember to still add the aforementioned line to /etc/fstab to have the RAM disk after a server reboot.

Now for MySQL:

Add this line in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=/var/tmpfs
```

and restart mysql.

**OPTION #3 : Get tmp table into the RAM Disk ASAP (assuming you apply OPTION #2 first)**

You may want to force tmp tables into the RAM disk as quickly as possible so that MySQL does not spin its wheels migrating large in-memory tmp tables into a RAM disk. Just add this to /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=/var/tmpfs
tmp_table_size=2K
```

and restart mysql. This will cause even the tiniest temp table to be brought into existence right in the RAM disk. You could periodically run `ls -l /var/tmpfs` to watch temp tables come and go.

Give it a Try !!!

**CAVEAT**

If you see nothing but temp tables in /var/tmpfs 24/7, this could impact OS functionality/performance. To make sure /var/tmpfs does not get overpopulated, look into tuning your queries. Once you do, you should see less tmp tables materializing in /var/tmpfs.

Comment: A few other points if you are on linux (specifically ubuntu)
You might need to add your tmpdir path to app armour in (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld)
Also dont forget to chmod 777 the dir as well!

Comment: When I try this on a ubuntu lamp server I'm getting job failed to start when I try to restart mysql. Then I switch it back to the default /tmp and it starts fine. @Dan Could you give an example for the bit you add to the user.sbin.mysqld ? Thanks

Comment: Just for reference I had to do the following on ubuntu besides adding in /etc/apparmor.d/usr/sbin.mysqld, I had to add to /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-tmp as well added in the same format as the orginal tmp folder.

Comment: I do not see files when I run `ls -l`. I've read that mysql creates the file, `rm`'s it and then writes to it *after it is `rm`'d*. Is that the case?

My query which writes to a temp table did not have its performance improve when utilizing this strategy. I still have ~5 seconds of time "copying to tmp table on disk". How do I verify my setup?

Comment: How can I found out size of tmpfs directory needed by mysql? and in which size mysql goes to use tempdir?

Answer (score 3):

You can also skip the copy to tmp table **on disk** part (not answered in the selected answer)

1. If you avoid some data types :

> Support for variable-length data types (including BLOB and TEXT) not supported by MEMORY.
>
> from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html
>   (or https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/memory-storage-engine/ if you are using mariadb).

2. If your temporary table is small enough : as said in selected answer, you can

   > Increase the variables tmp_table_size and/or max_heap_table_size

But if you split your query in smaller queries (not having the query does not help to analyze your problem), you can make it fit inside a memory temporary table.