# MySQL: Slow queries using "group by" - stuck in "Copying to tmp table"

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am working on a "leaderboard" for a web app relating to a sporting event, which reports the top 20 users based on their scores across all their responses to a multiple choice quiz. It also displays the current user's own rank within the leaderboard.

When this application is being load tested, the two queries concerned become very slow, spending a lot of time in "Copying to tmp table" state (up to 20 seconds per query). They do process eventually, but in the meantime hundreds can stack up.

In isolation given a reasonable number of rows in responses table, each query takes about 1 second to execute (25K users, e.g. 200K rows in responses)

I've added some indexes to the tables concerned, particularly for the FK columns and anything used in the where statements. I've also added a covering index for userID,answerID on the responses table.

This is the query for the leaderboard itself

```
SELECT users.username, sum(questions.points) as score FROM responses
JOIN answers on responses.answerID = answers.answerID
JOIN questions on answers.questionID = questions.questionID
JOIN users on responses.userID = users.userID
WHERE users.username != '' AND answers.isCorrect  
GROUP BY users.userID
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 20
```

This is the query to get the user's own rank within the results; a separate query gets their score first and then we count how many users have higher scores.

```
Select count(*) +1 as rank  from (
    SELECT users.username, sum(questions.points) as score
    FROM responses
    JOIN answers on responses.answerID = answers.answerID
    JOIN questions on answers.questionID = questions.questionID
    JOIN users on responses.userID = users.userID
    WHERE users.username != '' AND answers.isCorrect 
    GROUP BY users.userID
    HAVING sum(questions.points) > 2431
    ORDER BY score DESC
) as result
```

Simplified schema is

```
QUESTIONS
questionID
question
points

ANSWERS (multiple choice answers for question)
answerID
questionID
answer
isCorrect

RESPONSES (the player's choice of answer)
responseID
answerID
userID
```

I think these queries are done in a vaguely sensible way, but I would like to know if there is an obvious better way to do either of these that I have not considered.

Also, does anyone have any thoughts on why these queries stack up in "Copying to tmp table" state and just take so long to process when server is under load? I thought it might be creating them on disk but I see that is a separate state message. I have used EXPLAIN but my feeling is that the temp table is unavoidable with these queries; hence wondering by the "Copying to tmp table" takes so long

Constraints: not shown, users have teamIDs and queries are also filtered by teamID. Also not shown, there are several events and these queries can also be filtered by eventID. Also, not all questions have a correct answer at the time they're answered. Correct answers may be assigned at some future point, but at any rate at the end of the sporting event. The system reports percentages of users choosing each answer. So various ways of storing scores in a more aggregated way have been considered but discarded since they conflict with one or more of these constraints.

Hope this is enough to go on - many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have done stuff like this, and had similar problems.  The simultaneous queries pile up because they need to be serialized so each of them returns correct results in the moment they are run.

Good for you for catching it in load testing, rather than in production.

How do you solve this?

1. create a summary table that has the same columns as your summary query result.
2. create a stored procedure to extract the summary data from your detail tables and rewrite the summary table.
3. create an event to run your stored procedure at an appropriate interval.  How stale can your leaderboard display be?  Six seconds, a minute, an hour? That's how often your event should run. Your problem isn't the basic cost of the leaderboard extraction query. The problem comes from trying to run it a zillion times a minute.
4. rewrite your leaderboard display to pull stuff out of the summary table.

This way you're doing the hard stuff once for everybody, and the easy stuff per-user.

This will stabilize your application and let it scale up nicely.

Comment: Thanks for this; appreciate your reply. I considered implementing something vaguely similar, but what happens when leaderboard requests come in while the summary table is being repopulated?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?  If so, your update query will lock your summary table, and user requests will hang up for the second or so it takes to generate it, and then complete normally.  If you're using MyISAM, your stored procedure should probably lock the summary table explicitly to get the same effect.  If all this presents a terrible problem, you could try creating a new table, then locking the old one, deleting it, and renaming the new one to the old one's name.  But that's a total hairball to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

MySQL uses temp table if there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, and also in other cases listed there. You cannot bypass it.

So in your case the easiest solution for this may be setting up a RAM disk and making MySQL store the temp tables there, as described in:

[skip copying to tmp table on disk mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532307/skip-copying-to-tmp-table-on-disk-mysql)