# mysqld --defaults-file and tmpdir problems

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to make mysqld use my.cnf in a different location using the command below.

> ./bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/apps/local/mysql/my.cnf

It is not working and the server is not starting but if i start mysqld with the command below it works fine.

> ./bin/mysqld --datadir=/apps/local/mysql/data
>   --basedir=/apps/local/mysql --port=3306 --tmpdir=/tmp --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --pid-file=/apps/local/mysql/data/zizou.pid --log-error=/apps/local/mysql/data/zizou.err

Is there something wrong with my config file ? my.cnf looks as below.

```
[client] 
port=3306 
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld] 
# * Basic Settings
user=mysql 
pid-file=/apps/local/mysql/data/zizou.pid 
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock 
port=3306 
basedir=/apps/local/mysql 
datadir=/apps/local/mysql/data 
tmpdir=/tmp 
log-error=/apps/local/mysql/data/zizou.err 
lc-messages-dir=/apps/local/mysql
skip-external-locking

[mysqldump] 
quick
```

Also, i am using mysql database for drupal 6. It is using the default storage engine MYISAM. Recently, we saw an issue where the tmpdir is being used full. It only has space of 1GB. So, when we changed the tmpdir to a place where there is lot of storage, it has used 41GB in few hours of starting the server and its generating a lot of CPU load which is taking our website down.

We switched tmpdir to the directory with 1GB and there is no high CPU load and the website is working but the disk is being full. This is making me to clean it frequently. Are there any measures that i need to take to get out of this problem ?

**EDIT:** Can i keep deleting the .MYI and .MYD files and start the mysql server ? Is this healthy to do ?

Sorry for long post. These issues are bugging a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To setup different instance of mysql you can check here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-unix-servers.html

For tmpdir issue, probably you are running heavy queries.
You might get some help from here: [skip copying to tmp table on disk mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532307/skip-copying-to-tmp-table-on-disk-mysql)

Comment: Thank you. Drupal (Content Management System) is querying the database, i will also look in to common issues with drupal.