# Mariadb query (join) not using index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mariadb

When I do a simple query like for example the following:

```
SELECT `visits`.`item_id`, `visits`.`hits` FROM `visits` ORDER BY `visits`.`hits` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Well, it works and allow me to retrieve the top ten rows in the table `visits`.
However, when I join a table to retrieve information I need, it takes a lot more time (>1s), here's how i do it:

```
SELECT `visits`.`item_id`, `visits`.`hits`, `item`.`id`, `item`.`title`, `item`.`url` FROM `visits`
INNER JOIN `item` ON `visits`.`item_id`=`item`.`id`
ORDER BY `visits`.`hits` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Well, it does the job but takes more than a second to come up with the results. I ran the query with explain and it says:

```
id: simple
select_type: simple
table item
type ALL
possible_keys PRIMARY
key NULL
key_len NULL
ref NULL
Rows 4735
Extra Using temporary, using filesort

id: simple
select_type: simple
table visits
type ref
possible_keys visits_item_id
key visits_item_id
key_len 4
ref item.item_id
Rows 8
Extra
```

I'm no expert here but it looks to me like the query isn't using the index on `item`.`item_id` to find the `item`. And I don't know how to make this query run faster. Any ideas? any help will be so much appreciated, thanks!

`CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE `visits`(
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `visits_item_id` (`item_id`)
KEY `hits` (`hits`)
CONSTRAINT `visits_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=99427 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `item` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL
PRIMARY Key(`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6287 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**More info** I created these tables using `peewee`. After I created the tables with `Peewee` I then created the index on `visits`.`hits`.

** Show profile: by running `SET PROFILING=1;` **

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000106 |
| checking permissions | 0.000008 |
| checking permissions | 0.000003 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 |
| checking permissions | 0.000004 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000028 |
| After opening tables | 0.000007 |
| System lock          | 0.000006 |
| Table lock           | 0.000004 |
| After opening tables | 0.000006 |
| init                 | 0.000037 |
| optimizing           | 0.000033 |
| statistics           | 0.000075 |
| preparing            | 0.000049 |
| executing            | 0.000005 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.000510 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.813779 |
| Sorting result       | 0.027571 |
| Sending data         | 0.000040 |
| end                  | 0.000004 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000298 |
| end                  | 0.000005 |
| query end            | 0.000005 |
| closing tables       | 0.000013 |
| freeing items        | 0.000007 |
| updating status      | 0.000020 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000005 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables. I think the `item.item_id` is PRIMARY key, and if so, it is being used: `possible_keys PRIMARY`

Comment: Your joining clause is using the index however looks like the order by clause is creating the issue, you need to add an index for `visits.hits` and see the difference.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I updated my question with the information and thank you for the interest

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the `visits.hits` already has an index. Please see the updated version of my question!

Comment: `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT query here; SHOW PROFILE;` see the output here to find out where most of the time is spent.

Comment: @hjpotter92 thank you again. I just edited my question with the information.

Comment: As you can see from the results of profiling, the time lag is because of probably you being on a slow network (or the server, or both).

Comment: @hjpotter92 and then people says there's no place like home, sigh, I'm actually from my laptop. Didn't think that would be a problem. Thank you, :-)

Comment: @hjpotter92 I wasn't using the command line client yesterday, can you please take a look again at the output of `PROFILE`. It seems `Copying to tmp table  0.813779` is taking so much of the query time. Do you know any way I can improve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7533095/1190388

Answer (score 0):

Every InnoDB table must have a `PRIMARY KEY`, preferably explicitly specified.  You have `AUTO_INCREMENTs` -- make them the `PRIMARY KEY`, too.

Do you need both of these in the `SELECT` list; they are the same?.. `visits`.`item_id`, `item`.`id`